# Accessing tty1 through 6 takes unreasonably long

Tags: performance, tty

When I try to switch from the X session (tty7), it takes very long. Once in tty1-6, going to tty1-7 is instant.

It feels as if the time a tty7 -> ttyX switch takes was a function:
`tty7 -> ttyX loading time = 3 seconds + (length of the session inside ttyX)`

What could be the cause or how can I fix it?

Edit: Additional information

```
uname -a
Linux troll 3.16.0-31-generic #41~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 11 19:30:13 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


sudo lshw -c video
  *-display UNCLAIMED     
       description: 3D controller
       product: GM108M [GeForce 840M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:53 memory:f7400000-f77fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

Video driver: Intel i915
Ubuntu version: 14.04

Comment: Any graphics drivers you are using? Are you using nomodeset when booting from grub?  Any xorg messages when you flip to a TTY and then back to TTY7 (search for logs in dash and choose system log and click the xorg.xxx.log?

Comment: @fossfreedom I'm using the Intel i915 driver. I'm not using nomodeset. xorg messages: http://i.imgur.com/6vNQliZ.png.

Comment: @fossfreedom After the message "suspending AIGLX modules" I waited for 55 seconds at black screen and then I gave up and returned. The message structure is the same when the TTY actually loads.

Comment: Remember to add this sort of information into your question.  Please add what ubuntu version you are using together with the kernel version - uname -a ... this looks like an old intel bug.  If you are using 14.04 maybe the new kernel 3.16 + xorg HWE upgrade could fix this?

Comment: @fossfreedom Thank you. It appears that upgrading to kernel 3.16 has solved the "(length of the session inside ttyX)" bug. However, it still takes constant 2 seconds to reach the tty while on other, older machines with Ubuntu 14.04 it's instant so I can't consider the issue solved yet.

Comment: you said that you upgraded to 3.16 - but in the latest edit your are still using 3.13.  Please add the instructions to how you installed 3.16 together with the latest xorg-server components.

Comment: @fossfreedom my mistake, I didn't update the uname -a. I ran "apt-cache search linux-image" and then "sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-3.16.0-31-generic"

Answer (score 0):

This sounds very much like either/both a kernel and an xorg-server issue.

One potential solution is to install the 3.16 Utopic + latest xorg-server stack.

To do this you could follow the community recommended installation instructions:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

In summary:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic
```

However, I have noted in [my blog](https://xpressubuntu.wordpress.com/2015/02/12/how-to-upgrade-to-the-3-16-lts-utopic-kernel-and-graphics-for-ubuntu-14-04/) you should simulate this installation first and check carefully the packages that would be removed.

```
sudo apt-get -s install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic
```

Once you are happy that no vital packages will be removed, remove the -s parameter to install the Hardware Enablement Stack

Comment: I have installed it successfully, but I believe the old kernel is still being used. uname -a output hasn't changed. How do I switch to the new kernel?

Comment: @Grant - check that you havent pinned using an old kernel - if in doubt, from grub make sure you are booting from the 3.16 kernel.

Comment: there is only one 3.16 option in grub and that is the one I've installed yesterday. I should be booting into 14.04.2, right? The boot-repair tool says that it's probably too far on the disk for the bios to detect it. (http://i.imgur.com/f8Kal9f.png) By the way, I've patched the tty issue by using "i915.modeset=0 xforcevesa" parameter. The tty's are finally instant again. However it has a side effect that tty7 is now at constant 10 FPS (which is better than having to wait 2 seconds for tty's). If you add it to the answer, I can accept it. I'm still up to trying the 14.04.2 though.